# list of unique value from two columns

Tags: r, unique, dplyr

I want to create list of unique value form two columns. I work with network analysis dataset (undirected graph) and my dataset looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(unit1_name = c("unit 1","unit 1", "unit 2"), 
             unit2_name = c("unit 2","unit 3","unit 3"))
```

so I have all connections (called edges) between each elements (called nodes).

As a result I want to get a list:

```
unit 1
unit 2
unit 3
```

Of course I can write many code lines but is it possible to do it as fast as possible? Maybe in dplyr package?

Comment: why don't you show us the code you have and what you don't like about it and then we can suggest improvements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple approach would be:

```
unique(unlist(df))
#[1] unit 1 unit 2 unit 3
#Levels: unit 1 unit 2 unit 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like the `table` function in R. You can not only get the unique values but also the frequency for each value.

```
> table(unlist(df))

unit 1 unit 2 unit 3 
     2      2      2
```

If you want to access only the unique value instead of frequency in `table` object, you can just call the `names`.

```
> names(table(unlist(df)))
[1] "unit 1" "unit 2" "unit 3"
```

---

There is absolutely some overhead than pure `unique`, here I created a numeric vector of size 10million, these are their performance comparison.

```
> a <- sample(1:10, 1e7, replace=TRUE)
> system.time(unique(a))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.259   0.031   0.291 
> system.time(table(a))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.073   0.184   3.257
```